# How to make Round Rect Button in Nav bar open up homepage in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uibutton, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating a single view application with a `UIWebView` with a nav bar on top. In the nav bar, I want to create a button where, when pressed, will bring you back to the homepage of the `UIWebView`. Currently, when I press the 'home' button on the nav bar, it exits the application and brings me to the URL in Safari. Please help me fix this issue. My code is below:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIWebView *MyWebView;
}

//Buttons:
-(IBAction)HomeButton;
```

ViewController.m:

```
//Buttons:
-(IBAction)HomeButton {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    [MyWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the URL in your web view like you already do in `viewDidLoad` instead of calling `openURL:`.

```
-(IBAction)HomeButton {
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

[MyWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```

Btw. it is convention to start your property names with a lower case character. So you might want to rename `MyWebView` to `myWebView`.